# debug V8 with node-inspector

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, node-inspector

I'm trying to debug my JavaScript scripts, which are running in V8, with [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). On the app side, I just did

```
v8::Debug::EnableAgent("MyApp", 5858);
```

Node-inspector connects fine and even is able to pause/unpause and to show the code. However, step-wise execution does not work, neither breakpoints and probably a lot of other things. When I try to do such things, I get these errors from Node-inspector:

```
Node Inspector v0.7.0
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
Received request for a method not implemented: Debugger.setSkipAllPauses
Received request for a method not implemented: Debugger.setSkipAllPauses
Received request for a method not implemented: Debugger.setSkipAllPauses
Received request for a method not implemented: Debugger.setBreakpoint
Received request for a method not implemented: Debugger.setBreakpoint
Received request for a method not implemented: Debugger.setBreakpoint
```

So I guess I'm missing something.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even supported - because I guess, node-inspector is meant for Node.js and not for arbitrary V8, right? If so, what would be needed to make it work?

---

Thanks for the help by Miroslav, esp. to run `DEBUG=node-inspector:protocol:*  node-inspector`, I got a bit further. Step-wise execution works now, and breakpoints do to in most cases (except when you select the wrong Source file - see below).

I provided a global `process` object like this:

```
// process object: http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process
process.stdout = ...
process.stderr = ...
process._baseDir = ...
process.mainModule = {filename: process._baseDir + "/main.js"}
process.argv = ["myapp.exe", process.mainModule.filename]
process.cwd = function() { return process._baseDir; }
```

Now I get the error `Internal error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of null` in the console. In node-inspector, I get this:

```
Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:58:43 GMT node-inspector:protocol:v8-debug request: {"seq":170,"type":"request","command":"backtrace","arguments":{"inlineRefs":true,"fromFrame":0,"toFrame":50,"maxStringLength":10000}}
Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:58:43 GMT node-inspector:protocol:devtools frontend: {"method":"Debugger.setOverlayMessage","id":48}
Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:58:43 GMT node-inspector:protocol:devtools backend: {"id":48}
Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:58:43 GMT node-inspector:protocol:v8-debug response: {"seq":41,"request_seq":170,"type":"response","success":false,"message":"Internal error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of null"}
```

Another thing is that the script files are not always correct. On the C++ side, I'm loading them now like this:

```
ReturnType execJsFile(const std::string& jsSourceDir, const std::string& extfilename) {
    v8::TryCatch try_catch;

    std::string fullfilename = jsSourceDir + "/" + extfilename;
    std::string sourceStr;
    CHECK_RETURN(readFile(fullfilename, sourceStr));

    // The origin is for the debugger, e.g. node-inspector. It expects an URL.
    Local<String> origin = jsStr("file:///" + fullfilename);
    Local<String> source = jsStr(sourceStr);

    Local<v8::Script> script = Script::Compile(source, origin);
    if(script.IsEmpty()) {
        assert(try_catch.HasCaught());
        return "JS compile failed: " + jsReportExceptionToString(Isolate::GetCurrent(), &try_catch);;
    }

    Local<Value> result = script->Run();
    if(result.IsEmpty()) {
        assert(try_catch.HasCaught());
        return "JS script execution failed: " + jsReportExceptionToString(Isolate::GetCurrent(), &try_catch);
    }

    return true;
}
```

That puts all files under the `file://` domain in the Sources list. However, `main.js` gets an extra entry under `(no domain)`. When I make the change

```
process.mainModule = {filename: "file:///" + process._baseDir + "/main.js"}
```

it goes away, however, that is not how I would have expected ìt to be according to the [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

When I pause/break the execution in main.js, it shows up in yet another Source `[VM] main.js` and gets a yellow-ish background.

Also, all files in Sources under `file://` get the `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {` prefix added in the first line of the source. That line does not come from my code but from node-inspector. Why does it add that here? It is esp. strange because my code adds a slightly different prefix `( function(module, exports) {`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `DEBUG=node-inspector:protocol:* node-inspector` and inspect the messages, you might be able to find more information there. You can also try to use an older version, e.g. 0.1.9, it may have less dependencies on Node-specific stuff.

I'd say 95% of Node Inspector code uses V8 protocol only. Look for usages of `DebuggerClient.prototype.evaluateGlobal` to find where Node-specific functionality is used.

The first thing to change is `getResourceTree` in `lib/PageAgent.js`. Either implement your own way of listing all source files (including those not loaded yet), or return an empty tree.

**UPDATE**

Try Node's CLI debugger first:

```
$ node debug localhost:5858
```

To my best knowledge, the CLI debugger uses only the V8 debugger protocol features, nothing Node specific. When you are able to debug your V8 app using the CLI, you will know that any other problems are in Node Inspector and not in your V8 app.

Comment: I just recognized that you are the maintainer of node-inspector. :) Thanks for your answer, I will try out soon. Do you think that this might be a good feature for node-inspector, to be able to debug generic V8? Or maybe provide an extra package to include in a V8 app to be debug-able with node-inspector.

Comment: @Albert Node Inspector needs to know where the app is running to be able to find all project files. Plus we are detecting Node version (V8 version) to detect presence of certain debugger features like "setVariableValue". Given the limited amount of time I have to work on Node Inspector, it would be better if you change your V8 app to support these few Node APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got a bit further and extended my question. Right now, I'm trying to leave node-inspector unmodified and to extend my V8 by Nodejs-like global objects (e.g. I added `process`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for debugging V8 with node-inspector:

First of all, the latest version (0.12.3) has many extensions for debugging node.js scripts so I used an older version (0.5.0) which has less liability to node.js.

I used the following command to install v0.5.0 in Node.js command prompt:

```
npm install node-inspector@0.5.0
```

It is installed in folder "%USERPROFILE%\node_modules" by default.

I added one line of code to %USERPROFILE%\node_modules\node-inspector\lib\PageAgent.js:

```
getResourceTree: function(params, done) {
    return; //return empty tree
...
```

This completes the installation.

Here is the guide to debug a javascript file executed by using the ClearScript .NET library:

Open a command prompt and execute the following command:

%USERPROFILE%\node_modules\.bin\node-inspector.cmd

You should see the following lines if node-inspector is running successfully.

```
Node Inspector v0.5.0
info - socket.io started 
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

Initialize your V8 engine as in the following code line (VB.NET code):

Dim engine As New V8ScriptEngine("global", V8ScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging, 9222)

Put a breakpoint right after this line in your code and run your application to reach this breakpoint.

Make sure you have "debugger;" statement in the first line of your JavaScript code.

Open a Chrome browser and navigate to the following address:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=9222

Press "Continue Debugging" button in Vİsual Studio toolbar.

Now you should see your script code stopped at the first "debugger;" line in Chrome browser.

You can continue debugging from here.